# Objective-C foreach is the enumerable object guaranteed to be called just once?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

let's suppose iam doing

```
for (UserCollection * userCollection in [smth fetchUserCollections]) {

}
```

**is there a guarantee that [user fetchUserCollection] gets called just once at the beginning of the for each?**

or i shouldn't count on it?

Comment: It _should_ only get called once but why depend on that? Just use another line. If it's making you question how it works, it might confuse whoever inherits your code.

Comment: On the other hand, putting it in a variable (on another line) might make the inheritor have to figure out if that variable is used again later.  This way, it's clear the result of `fetchUserCollections` is only used in the loop.

Comment: There's certainly no harm in assigning the value to a temp and using the temp.  Among other things this makes debugging simpler, and it will not generally cause any performance degradation.  It's very easy to get lost in "long chain polymer" statements, and very hard to debug when you do.

Comment: @HotLicks There is "no harm" in many things, each adding mysterious complexity and smell everywhere. Source of confusion is of course lack of documentation, but it is missing for a reason -- this is actually a common sense that generated code doesn't operate on symbolic expressions, but only on evaluated results (except for "macros" thing, which is never part of the language, except for lisplikes). Expression is always reduced into value once and only then fed to `for(x in y)` construct. There is no such thing as "reusable call".

Comment: @user3125367 -- I haven't the foggiest idea what your rant is about.

Comment: @HotLicks Not ranting at all, the question raised is a common fear, and someone may find this pretty explaining :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well…

I don't know of any **official** Apple or clang documentation guaranteeing that it's only called once.  There's no specification for the Objective-C language.

On the other hand…

You can count on it being called only once.  That's the way it works today, it would be a performance regression to call it repeatedly, and it would probably break a lot of code that works today.

For example, you wouldn't be able to do this:

```
for (Card *card in [deck shuffledArrayOfCards]) {
    ...
}
```

because you'd get back a new random ordering on each call.

Under the covers, your program calls `[smth fetchUserCollections]` once at the start of the loop and saves the result.  The result is an object that implements the `NSFastEnumeration` protocol.  It then sends  `countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:` to the `NSFastEnumeration` object repeatedly until the object stops returning elements.  The loop sends multiple messages to the `NSFastEnumeration` object, but only one message to your `smth` object.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [rob mayoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77567/rob-mayoff) about `NSFastEnumeration`. I verified it myself with a quick code test below and I don't see any reason why the `for...in` structure would change for any other implementation of an enumerable collection.

EDIT: Good suggestions! I've updated my test to have a static counter and a significantly bigger array and it still shows the same result -- that the enumerated object is collected only once. It's worth noting in Apple's documentation for [Fast Enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Enumerators.html) specifically where it says "The enumerator raises an exception if you modify the collection while enumerating." While this doesn't confirm exactly what the OP was asking, it does seem to imply that the collection is retrieved only once.

Also worth noting -- when I ran this test with size set to `NSUIntegerMax`, it raised a nice exception :)

```
capacity (18446744073709551615) is ridiculous
```

Code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FastEnumer : NSObject
- (NSArray *)enumeratedArrayOfSize:(NSUInteger)size;
@end

@implementation FastEnumer

- (NSArray *)enumeratedArrayOfSize:(NSUInteger)size
{
    // counts how many times this method is called
    static NSUInteger calledCount = 0;
    NSLog(@"(Enumerated) Called: %ld\n", ++calledCount);

    // populates an array of NSStrings of alphabet letters to enumerate
    static NSMutableArray *testArray = nil;
    if (!testArray) {
        testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:size];
        NSArray *sample = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H",
                            @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P",
                            @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X",
                            @"Y", @"Z"];
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            [testArray addObject:sample[i % sample.count]];
        }
    }
    return testArray;
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        // flag to note loop behavior
        BOOL started = NO;

        // testing class for the 'for...in' fast enumeration
        FastEnumer *myTest = [[FastEnumer alloc] init];

        // set number of items in array and use Fast Enumeration construct
        NSUInteger size = 1000000000; // 1 billion
        for (NSString *letter in [myTest enumeratedArrayOfSize:size]) {

            // show loop has begun
            if (!started) {
                NSLog(@"Started 'for...in' loop with %@", letter);
                started = YES;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2014-09-26 14:16:45.826 Scratchy[8222:303] (Enumerated) Called: 1
2014-09-26 14:17:40.346 Scratchy[8222:303] Started 'for...in' loop with A
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good test. May want to throw a static counter in there to see how many times enumeratedArray is actually called. May also want to increase the size of the array, given how NSFastEnumeration buffers the content.

Comment: You would definitely need to increase the size of the array for a valid test.  Last time I checked, I believe I found that `NSFastEnumeration` returns 16 elements per call.  (This is determined by the compiler.)